# Locating row in index page

Tags: sql-server, clustered-index

In clustered index, we have root, intermediate and leaf level pages. Every page has few records where indicating range of pages from level below.

How SQL check whether some index key belong to specific range, that is, which operation it uses for that?

Is it cursor, which traverse through all rows from one page, or something else?

Comment: Have you read through the Clustered Index Structure on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177443(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: OK, good reference, but not explained how SQL Server check in one index page whether key value exists or not. By example, if we have page which keep values from 1-100, and I search for 55, by which mechanism SQL get a knowledge that this value is on that page?

Answer (score 5):

The default algorithm to locate a particular record in an index is a [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) using the [row offset array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/pages-and-extents-architecture-guide):

[image]

Enterprise Edition may also use interpolation based on [linear regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression) information:

[image: Linear Regression]

I wrote about the details and the performance implications in [SQL Server, Seeks, and Binary Search](https://www.sql.kiwi/2011/08/sql-server-seeks-and-binary-search.html).